# Xubuntu kills all apps after login

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, lock-screen, suspend

I am using Xubuntu 18.04. After fresh install I customized my desktop as I usually do (installed some packages and changed some config). Anyhow I am not sure when it began but once I locked screen (xflock4 / ctrl + alt + del) my display blacked out (in past I just got login screen) for few seconds.

If I press any key, login screen appears but once I enter my password it looks like xserver restarts or whatever, in top left corner I see `started bpfilter` and then **another** login screen appears. When I enter my password again I got to desktop but all my started apps are gone. It looks like my session got restarted.

I somehow managed to solve this "locking" issue [by uninstalling light-locker and installing xscreensaver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124543/169105).

Anyhow today I found that same problem happens when I **suspend** my computer. There is something terribly wrong with my desktop. I am newbie and really dont know how to debug this.